# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table ... that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, composite-key

I am getting this error while creating the table `[dbo].[WeibullSummaryDetails]`.

These are my two tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeibullFilterDetails]
(
        [WeibullFilterDetailsId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ProjectTeamId] int not null,
        [WeekStartDate] date not NULL,
        [WeekEndDate] date  not null ,
        [IsRefreshed] bit NULL,

        CONSTRAINT FK_WeibullFilterDetails_WeibullFilterDetails 
            FOREIGN KEY ([ProjectTeamId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[ProjectTeams]([Id]),
        PRIMARY KEY ([ProjectTeamId], [WeibullFilterDetailsId])
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeibullSummaryDetails]
(
    [WeibullSummaryDetailsId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WeibullFilterDetailsId] int not null,
    [ProjectTeamId] int not null,
    [ActualEstimatedBugCount] int NULL,
    [CurrentBugCount] int NULL,
    [PercentageBugFound] float NULL,
    [PercentageBugResolved] float NULL,
    [BugsToFind] int NULL,
    BugsToResolve int NULL,
    LinearEquation nvarchar(100) null,
    RSquare float NULL,
    Shape float NULL,
    Scale float NULL

    PRIMARY KEY ([WeibullSummaryDetailsId], [WeibullFilterDetailsId],[ProjectTeamId]),
    CONSTRAINT FK_WeibullSummaryDetails_WeibullFilterDetails 
        FOREIGN KEY ([WeibullFilterDetailsId],[ProjectTeamId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[WeibullFilterDetails]([WeibullFilterDetailsId],[ProjectTeamId])
)
```

Detailed error message

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 14
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.WeibullFilterDetails' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_WeibullSummaryDetails_WeibullFilterDetails'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 14
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I have seen other posts on this error, usually the solution given is that if parent table has a composite key, then both the columns should be present in the child table too and should be used for the foreign key constraint.

That is exactly what I am doing here, but still getting this error.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `[dbo].[WeibullFilterDetails]` you defined the primary key as `([ProjectTeamId],[WeibullFilterDetailsId])`, yet in your `REFERENCES` clause you wrote `([WeibullFilterDetailsId],[ProjectTeamId])` -- the order doesn't match. Try:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeibullSummaryDetails](
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY ([ProjectTeamId],[WeibullFilterDetailsId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[WeibullFilterDetails]([ProjectTeamId],[WeibullFilterDetailsId])
);
```